# How to automate legends for a new geom in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend, ggproto

I've built this new `ggplot2` geom layer I'm calling `geom_triangles` (see https://github.com/ctesta01/ggtriangles/) that plots isosceles triangles given aesthetics including `x, y, z` where `z` is the height of the triangle and
the base of the isosceles triangle has midpoint (x,y) on the graph.

What I want is for the `geom_triangles()` layer to automatically provide legend components for the height and width of the triangles, but I am not sure how to do that.

I understand based on [this reference](https://tidyverse.github.io/ggplot2-docs/articles/extending-ggplot2.html) that I may need to adjust the `draw_key` argument in the `ggproto` `StatTriangles` object, but I'm not sure how I would do that and can't seem to find examples online of how to do it. I've been looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/main/R/legend-draw.r) in `ggplot2` for the `draw_key` functions, but I'm not sure how I would introduce multiple legend components (one for each of height and width) in a single `draw_key` argument in the `StatTriangles` `ggproto`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggrepel)
library(tibble)
library(cowplot)
library(patchwork)

StatTriangles <- ggproto("StatTriangles", Stat,
  required_aes = c('x', 'y', 'z'),
  compute_group = function(data, scales, params, width = 1, height_scale = .05, width_scale = .05, angle = 0) {

    # specify default width
    if (is.null(data$width)) data$width <- 1

    # for each row of the data, create the 3 points that will make up our
    # triangle based on the z, width, height_scale, and width_scale given.
        triangle_df <-
            tibble::tibble(
                group = 1:nrow(data),
                point1 = lapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) {with(data, c(x[[i]] - width[[i]]/2*width_scale, y[[i]]))}),
                point2 = lapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) {with(data, c(x[[i]] + width[[i]]/2*width_scale, y[[i]]))}),
                point3 = lapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) {with(data, c(x[[i]], y[[i]] + z[[i]]*height_scale))})
            )

        # pivot the data into a long format so that each coordinate pair (e.g. vertex)
        # will be its own row
        triangle_df <- triangle_df %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(
            cols = c(point1, point2, point3),
            names_to = 'vertex',
            values_to = 'coordinates'
        )

        # extract the coordinates -- this must be done rowwise because
        # coordinates is a list where each element is a c(x,y) coordinate pair
        triangle_df <- triangle_df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(
            x = coordinates[[1]],
            y = coordinates[[2]])

        # save the original x and y so we can perform rotations by the
        # given angle with reference to (orig_x, orig_y) as the fixed point
        # of the rotation transformation
    triangle_df$orig_x <- rep(data$x, each = 3)
    triangle_df$orig_y <- rep(data$y, each = 3)

    # i'm not sure exactly why, but if the group isn't interacted with linetype
    # then the edges of the triangles get messed up when rendered when linetype
    # is used in an aesthetic
    # triangle_df$group <-
    #   paste0(triangle_df$orig_x, triangle_df$orig_y, triangle_df$group, rep(data$group, each = 3))

        # fill in aesthetics to the dataframe
    triangle_df$colour <- rep(data$colour, each = 3)
    triangle_df$size <- rep(data$size, each = 3)
    triangle_df$fill <- rep(data$fill, each = 3)
    triangle_df$linetype <- rep(data$linetype, each = 3)
    triangle_df$alpha <- rep(data$alpha, each = 3)
    triangle_df$angle <- rep(data$angle, each = 3)

    # determine scaling factor in going from y to x
    # scale_factor <- diff(range(data$x)) / diff(range(data$y))
    scale_factor <- diff(scales$x$get_limits()) / diff(scales$y$get_limits())
    if (! is.finite(scale_factor) | is.na(scale_factor)) scale_factor <- 1

    # rotate the data according to the angle by first subtracting out the
    # (orig_x, orig_y) component, applying coordinate rotations, and then
    # adding the (orig_x, orig_y) component back in.
        new_coords <- triangle_df %>% mutate(
      x_diff = x - orig_x,
      y_diff = (y - orig_y) * scale_factor,
      x_new = x_diff * cos(angle) - y_diff * sin(angle),
      y_new = x_diff * sin(angle) + y_diff * cos(angle),
      x_new = orig_x + x_new*scale_factor,
      y_new = (orig_y + y_new)
        )

        # overwrite the x,y coordinates with the newly computed coordinates
        triangle_df$x <- new_coords$x_new
        triangle_df$y <- new_coords$y_new

    triangle_df
  }
)

stat_triangles <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "polygon",
                       position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                       inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatTriangles, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}

GeomTriangles <- ggproto("GeomTriangles", GeomPolygon,
    default_aes = aes(
            color = 'black', fill = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = 1, alpha = 1, angle = 0, width = 1
        )
)

geom_triangles <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
                       position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                       inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatTriangles, geom = GeomTriangles, data = data, mapping = mapping,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}

# here's an example using mtcars 

plt_orig <- mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column('name') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = disp, z = cyl, width = wt, color = hp, fill = hp, label = name)) +
  geom_triangles(width_scale = 10, height_scale = 15, alpha = .7) +
  geom_point(color = 'black', size = 1) +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(color = 'black', size = 2, nudge_y = -10) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(end = .6) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(end = .6) +
  xlab("miles per gallon") +
  ylab("engine displacement (cu. in.)") +
  labs(fill = 'horsepower', color = 'horsepower') +
  ggtitle("MPG, Engine Displacement, # of Cylinders, Weight, and Horsepower of Cars from the 1974 Motor Trends Magazine",
  "Cylinders shown in height, weight in width, horsepower in color") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10), plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 8), legend.title = element_text(size = 10))

plt_orig
```

[image: first plot example with mtcars, geom_triangles, and color legend]

What I have been able to do is to write helper functions (`draw_geom_triangles_height_legend`, `draw_geom_triangles_width_legend`) and use the `patchwork`, and `cowplot` packages to make legend components rather manually and combining them in an appropriate grid with the original plot, but I want to make producing these legend components automatic. The following code also uses the `ggrepel` package to add text labels in the figure.

```
draw_geom_triangles_height_legend <- function(
  width = 1,
  width_scale = .1,
  height_scale = .1,
  z_values = 1:3,
  n.breaks = 3,
  labels = c("low", "medium", "high"),
  color = 'black',
  fill = 'black'
) {
  ggplot(
    data = data.frame(x = rep(0, times = n.breaks),
                      y = seq(1,n.breaks),
                      z = quantile(z_values, seq(0, 1, length.out = n.breaks)) %>% as.vector(),
                      width = width,
                      label = labels,
                      color = color,
                      fill = fill
    ),
    mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, label = label, width = width)
  ) +
    geom_triangles(width_scale = width_scale, height_scale = height_scale, color = color, fill = fill) +
    geom_text(mapping = aes(x = x + .5), size = 3) +
    expand_limits(x = c(-.25, 3/4)) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = .5))
}

draw_geom_triangles_width_legend <- function(
  width = 1:3,
  width_scale = .1,
  height_scale = .1,
  z_values = 1,
  n.breaks = 3,
  labels = c("low", "medium", "high"),
  color = 'black',
  fill = 'black'
) {
  ggplot(
    data = data.frame(x = rep(0, times = n.breaks),
                      y = seq(1, n.breaks),
                      z = rep(1, n.breaks),
                      width = width,
                      label = labels,
                      color = color,
                      fill = fill
    ),
    mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, label = label, width = width)
  ) +
    geom_triangles(width_scale = width_scale, height_scale = height_scale, color = color, fill = fill) +
    geom_text(mapping = aes(x = x + .5), size = 3) +
    expand_limits(x = c(-.25, 3/4)) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = .5))
}

# extract the original legend - this is for the color and fill (hp)
legend_hp <- cowplot::get_legend(plt_orig)

# remove the legend from the plot
plt <- plt_orig + theme(legend.position = 'none')

# create a height legend using draw_geom_triangles_height_legend
height_legend <- 
  draw_geom_triangles_height_legend(z_values = c(min(mtcars$cyl), median(mtcars$cyl), max(mtcars$cyl)),
                                    labels = c(min(mtcars$cyl), median(mtcars$cyl), max(mtcars$cyl))
                                    ) +
                                    ggtitle("cylinders\n")


# create a width legend using draw_geom_triangles_width_legend
width_legend <- 
  draw_geom_triangles_width_legend(
  width = quantile(mtcars$wt, c(.33, .66, 1)),
  labels = round(quantile(mtcars$wt, c(.33, .66, 1)), 2),
  width_scale = .2
  ) +
  ggtitle("weight\n(1000 lbs)\n")

blank_plot <- ggplot() + theme_void()
  
# create a legend column layout
# 
# whitespace is used above, below, and in-between the legend components to
# make sure the legend column pieces don't appear too densely stacked.
# 
legend_component <-
  (blank_plot /  cowplot::plot_grid(legend_hp) / blank_plot /  height_legend / blank_plot / width_legend / blank_plot) +
  plot_layout(heights = c(1, 1, .5, 1, .5, 1, 1))

# create the layout with the plot and the legend component
(plt + legend_component) + 
  plot_layout(nrow = 1, widths = c(1, .15))
```

[image: second plot with mtcars, geom_triangles, with added legend components for height and width]

What I'm looking for is to be able to run the code for the first plot example and get a legend with 3 components similar to the color/fill, height, and width legend components as in the second plot example.

Unfortunately the helper functions are not at all satisfactory because at present one has to rely on visually estimating whether the legend's `height_scale` and `width_scale` components look correct. This is because the lengeds produced by `draw_geom_triangles_height_legend` and `draw_geom_triangles_width_legend` are their own `ggplot` objects and therefore aren't necessarily on the same coordinate scaling system as the main `ggplot` of interest for which they are supposed to be legends.

Both of the plots I included are rendered at 7in x 8.5in using `ggsave`.

Here's my R `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] patchwork_1.1.1 cowplot_1.1.1   tibble_3.1.6    ggrepel_0.9.1   dplyr_1.0.7     magrittr_2.0.1  ggplot2_3.3.5   colorout_1.2-2 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7        tidyselect_1.1.1  munsell_0.5.0     viridisLite_0.4.0 colorspace_2.0-2  R6_2.5.1          rlang_0.4.12      fansi_0.5.0      
 [9] tools_4.1.2       grid_4.1.2        gtable_0.3.0      utf8_1.2.2        DBI_1.1.2         withr_2.4.3       ellipsis_0.3.2    digest_0.6.29    
[17] yaml_2.2.1        assertthat_0.2.1  lifecycle_1.0.1   crayon_1.4.2      tidyr_1.1.4       farver_2.1.0      purrr_0.3.4       vctrs_0.3.8      
[25] glue_1.6.0        labeling_0.4.2    compiler_4.1.2    pillar_1.6.4      generics_0.1.1    scales_1.1.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be slightly overcomplicating things. Ideally, you'd just want a single key drawing method for the whole layer. However, because you're using a `Stat` to do the majority of calculations, this becomes hairy to implement. In my answer, I'm avoiding this.

Let's say I'd want to use a geom-only implementation of such a layer. I can make the following (simplified) class/constructor pair. Below, I haven't bothered `width_scale` or `height_scale` parameters, just for simplicity.

#### Class

```r
library(ggplot2)

GeomTriangles <- ggproto(
  "GeomTriangles", GeomPoint,
  default_aes = aes(
    colour = "black", fill = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = 1, 
    alpha = 1, angle = 0, width = 0.5, height = 0.5
  ),
  
  draw_panel = function(
    data, panel_params, coord, na.rm = FALSE
  ) {
    # Apply coordinate transform
    df <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
    
    # Repeat every row 3x
    idx <- rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each = 3)
    rep_df <- df[idx, ]
    # Calculate offsets from origin
    x_off <- as.vector(outer(c(-0.5, 0, 0.5), df$width))
    y_off <- as.vector(outer(c(0, 1, 0), df$height))
    
    # Rotate offsets
    ang <- rep_df$angle * (pi / 180)
    x_new <- x_off * cos(ang) - y_off * sin(ang)
    y_new <- x_off * sin(ang) + y_off * cos(ang)
    
    # Combine offsets with origin
    x <- unit(rep_df$x, "npc") + unit(x_new, "cm")
    y <- unit(rep_df$y, "npc") + unit(y_new, "cm")
    
    grid::polygonGrob(
      x = x, y = y, id = idx,
      gp = grid::gpar(
        col  = alpha(df$colour, df$alpha),
        fill = alpha(df$fill, df$alpha),
        lwd  = df$size * .pt,
        lty  = df$linetype
      )
    )
  }
)
```

#### Constructor

```r
geom_triangles <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
                           position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                           inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = "identity", geom = GeomTriangles, data = data, mapping = mapping,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}
```

#### Example

Just to show how it works without any special keys set. I'm letting a continuous scale for `width` and `height` take over the job of your `width_scale` and `height_scale` parameters, because I didn't want to focus on that here. As you can see, two legends are made automatically, but with the wrong glyphs.

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, height = cyl, width = wt, colour = hp, fill = hp)) +
  geom_triangles() +
  geom_point(colour = "black") +
  continuous_scale("width", "wscale",  
                   palette = scales::rescale_pal(c(0.1, 0.5))) +
  continuous_scale("height", "hscale", 
                   palette = scales::rescale_pal(c(0.1, 0.5)))
```

[image]

#### Glyphs

Writing a function to draw a glyph isn't too difficult. In this case, we do almost the same as `GeomTriangles$draw_panel`, but we fix the `x` and `y` positions of the origin, and don't use a coordinate transform.

```r
draw_key_triangle <- function(data, params, size) {
  # browser()
  idx <- rep(seq_len(nrow(data)), each = 3)
  rep_data <- data[idx, ]
  
  x_off <- as.vector(outer(
    c(-0.5, 0, 0.5),
    data$width
  ))
  
  y_off <- as.vector(outer(
    c(0, 1, 0),
    data$height
  ))
  
  ang <- rep_data$angle * (pi / 180)
  x_new <- x_off * cos(ang) - y_off * sin(ang)
  y_new <- x_off * sin(ang) + y_off * cos(ang)
  
  # Origin x and y have fixed values
  x <- unit(0.5, "npc") + unit(x_new, "cm")
  y <- unit(0.2, "npc") + unit(y_new, "cm")
  
  grid::polygonGrob(
    x = x, y = y, id = idx,
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col  = alpha(data$colour, data$alpha),
      fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha),
      lwd  = data$size * .pt,
      lty  = data$linetype
    )
  )
  
}
```

When we now provide this glyph drawing function to the layer, it should draw the correct legends automatically.

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, height = cyl, width = wt, colour = hp, fill = hp)) +
  geom_triangles(key_glyph = draw_key_triangle) +
  geom_point(colour = "black") +
  continuous_scale("width", "wscale",  
                   palette = scales::rescale_pal(c(0.1, 0.5))) +
  continuous_scale("height", "hscale", 
                   palette = scales::rescale_pal(c(0.1, 0.5)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The ideal place for the glyph constructor is in the ggproto class. So a final ggproto class could look like:

```r
GeomTriangles <- ggproto(
  "GeomTriangles", GeomPoint,
  ..., # Whatever you want to put in here
  draw_key = draw_key_triangle
)
```

Footnote: using scales for width and height isn't generally recommended because it may affect other geoms as well.

Comment: This is excellent!  A clarifying question I'd like to ask:  If "using scales for width and height isn't generally recommended because it may affect other geoms as well" is it appropriate to assume it would be better practice to rename the aesthetics something like "triangle_height" and "triangle_width" so as to not potentially mess up aesthetics from other geoms?

Comment: Yes that should be perfectly safe and oughtn't conflict with other geoms :)

Comment: do you have any idea why this implementation doesn't support a negative height argument?  I can't seem to figure out why it's not supported, but if I print out data$height or df$height inside the ggproto, it's all positive no matter how I specify the height aesthetics to begin with.  I realize that I could have an indicator that maps positive to angle = 0º and negative to angle = 180º, but I'd also like to support negative heights without having to use the angle argument at all.

Comment: Are you using the height scale as in my answer above or not? If you are, you might have to set a different palette range for negative values.

Comment: I renamed things to use "triangle_height", and "triangle_width" for the aesthetics and then "triangle_hscale" and "triangle_wscale" in the continuous_scale calls.  It looks like if I call grid.draw() on the output of the draw_key_triangle, that supports negative arguments to triangle_height, but the ggproto I constructed with the same body as your draw_key_triangle in the draw_panel function, just with `df <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)` added at the beginning, appears to already have only positive data in the triangle_height column if I print out data or before any other steps.

Comment: I've written out the full ggproto implementation here: https://github.com/ctesta01/ggtriangles/blob/main/R/geom_triangles.R and included a commented out example that shows the lack of negative number support I'm mentioning.  I hope this makes my question more concrete.

Comment: Right, but does changing the range of the palette allow negative values? E.g. `range = c(-1, 1)` in L190 of the linked code.

Comment: Oh you're totally right.  Using the range arguments to continuous_scale along with specifying the legend breaks and limits manually let's me do what I want.  This is fabulous, thanks!